# how to hide UItableView only when search result is 0

Tags: swift, uitableview, uisearchbar

I am trying to hide tableViewUsers when the result of the search is 0. but my logic hides the UItableView and the UISearchBar "Located on table header" is the result is 0.what I want to view "No result View" and keep search bar visible to the user to search again?

Code

```
public func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    searchBar.showsCancelButton = true
    filteredUsers = users.filter {
        $0.username.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil ||
            $0.email.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil
    }

    if(filteredUsers.count ==  0){
        tableViewUsers.isHidden = true
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        view.addSubview(NoItemFoundVIew)
        NoItemFoundVIew.center = view.center
    }
    else
    {
        tableViewUsers.reloadData()
    }

}
```

Comment: How about using tableView.backgroundView property?
You can also just set backgroundColor to .clear.
I don't get the searchBar is in the header, but OK.

Comment: can you show me in code ?

Comment: Try setting the backgroundColor to .clear. In this case it should work, although not the best. I also suggest constraint in the centre the NoItemFoundVIew if you use your approach and not use the centre property.

Comment: Else you can set tableView.backgroundView = NoItemFoundView() and set it to nil when you have results

Comment: Also simulator has printScreen functionality built in. Command+S

Comment: can you make your comments as an answer ?

Comment: OK, I did. Does it work?

Comment: no. it is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is how I do it

```
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    view.addSubview(NoItemFoundVIew)
    NoItemFoundVIew.center = view.center
    tableViewUsers.reloadData()
    tableViewUsers.separatorStyle = .none
```

Answer (score -1):

In your case even setting the background color of your custom view to .clear should be enough:

```
view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
```

I suggest using constraints to add your view and not using the .center property, but is up to you.

Else you can use the backgroundView property of the tableView with whatever initialiser your custom view has.

```
tableView.backgroundView = NoItemFoundView()
```

And remove it when you have results.

```
tableView.backgroundView = nil
```